# React native: Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Unfortunately i am having a classic "now only god knows" moments with the code (or because it was written by my team member).
I am returning to a project that has been put away for quite some time and now upon returning and trying to update some packages etc. etc. i am getting some annoying errors.

The main one now is this when im trying to run my React Native project:

```
* http://blurred-IP/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:150165:37 in _callee$
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:30 in invoke
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:28 in invoke
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:170:17 in Promise$argument_0
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:45:7 in tryCallTwo
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:200:23 in doResolve
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:66:12 in Promise
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:169:27 in Promise$argument_0
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:192:38 in enqueue
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:216:8 in exports.async
* src/screens/main/DashBoard.js:150:18 in splitServices
* http:blurred-IP/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:150661:69 in fetchEverything$
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:30 in invoke
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:28 in invoke
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:145:19 in Promise.resolve.then$argument_0
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:146:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:194:17 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:458:30 in callImmediates
* [native code]:null in callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:407:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:143:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:142:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

So as far as i can see the problem should appear at line 150 in the file DashBoard.js.
That line and the code around it:

```js
 async fetchEverything() {
    const services = await NetworkingService.fetchActiveServices()
    const events = await NetworkingService.fetchAllEvents()
    const things = await NetworkingService.fetchAllThings()
    const splitservices = await this.splitServices(services)
    await this.setStateAsync({
      eventData: events.events,
      requestData: splitservices.requests,
      offerData: splitservices.offers,
      thingData: things.data.things,
    })
    this.createRenders()
  }

  splitServices = async (services) => {
    const list = services.services
    const requests = []
    const offers = []
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (list[i].type === 'REQUEST') {
        requests.push(list[i])
      } else {
        offers.push(list[i])
      }
    }
    return { requests, offers }
  }
// Code continues beneath here
```

Something about the list possibly being empty? Being empty?

Any help will be mostly appreciated!

Comment: My guess is `services` is undefined when you are trying to access `services.services`. I think you need to check if `NetworkingService.fetchActiveServices()` is returning a valid response.

Answer (score 0):

change the variable value from undefined to {} (empty object) should work, had this problem awhile ago this solved it.

*Edited*:
or to []

Comment: probably here, try const 
list = services.services ?? []

Comment: and also declare your function before calling it